# How can an observer observe the metric of spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, measurements

I don't mean how can we measure the metric in practice. I only mean in principle. Suppose you are an omnipresent being, no experimental limitations. What measurements do you need to measure the metric at a point?

Also, you can deduce the metric from the Energy Momentum Tensor, sure. I don't want that answer. The answer I want is "How can we deduce the metric by making measurements about the geometry of spacetime"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Directly measuring the geometry is not practical, as the measurements would be too hard to make. But it could be done *in principle*. You just need to parallel transport a vector around a loop and measure how much this vector has changed. The change in the direction of the vector is directly related to the Riemann tensor.

Suppose you take a vector and you parallel transport it round a small square:

[image: Parallel transport]

Obviously when you finish going round the square you'll be back at your starting point and the vector will still be pointing in the same direction.

But this is *only* true when the spacetime you're moving through is *flat*. If you try this on a curved spacetime you'll find that after completing the square you won't be back at your starting point and the vector may have rotated away from it's original direction.

[image: Parallel transport on sphere]

In this diagram the red vector is the initial vector at $P$, and we find that when we get back to our starting point, the angle of the vector has changed.

The change in the vector is described by the [Riemann tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor), and in General Relativity the Riemann tensor is what determines the metric. So we can measure the metric by measuring the geometry.

In practice, the changes around any loop of a practical size would be too small to measure so this direct measurement could not be done. Instead you would do indirect measurements. For example just dropping an object and measuring its trajectory is a way of indirectly determining the metric since the acceleration is determined by the Christoffel symbols, which are determined by the metric.

Comment: Is there also a method in which we figure out whatever formula is the equivalent of the Pythagoras theorem? We'd figure out that formula by doing some distance measurements?

Comment: @RainDeer Yes, for example you could draw circles and measure the radii and circumferences and measure the deviations from $c = 2\pi r$, but these tend to produce measurements that are integrals of the metric so they are indirect.

Comment: With infinitesimal right traingles? You make a clock move along an infinitesimal tangent vector $dx^{\mu}$. If the clock changes time by $d {\tau}$, then the metric is some scalar function $f(dx^{\mu})=d\tau$?

Comment: @JohnRennie but is there a direct generic processing route from Reimann to the metric?  I don't recall seeing that anywhere, and can't think how it could be done.

Comment: @m4r35n357 good question. You can go from the metric to the Christoffel symbols and thence to the Riemann tensor, but I'm not sure about the reverse direction.

Comment: @m4r35n357 I read (in Carroll's book) something like "The number of free parameters in the second derivative of the metric is the same as the number of free parameters of the Riemann curvature Tensor". (Both 20 something). So solving for the metric should involve setting the metric at a point to be equal to the Minkowski metric, setting its first derivatives to zero, and solving for the second derivative using the 20 something Riemann tensor entries.

Comment: @m4r35n357 The book didn't *exactly* say this. It said that if you *try* to set the second derivative to zero, it's not always possible because you're left with 20 something free parameters in the second derivative of the metric. This stuff is in chapter 2 of Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry

Comment: @RainDeer the problem that I see is that Riemann is made up of mixed derivatives, perhaps the method you describe can handle that, but as I understand it you would have a "solution" that would need to be (in some sense) "integrated twice" to get a metric, so it would be "non-unique" (in some sense); I am clearly at my limits here ;)

Comment: @m4r35n357:  If you know the components of the Riemann tensor with respect to an orthogonal basis at some point, then you can extend these basis vectors to construct [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) in a neighborhood of that point so that $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} - \frac13 R_{\mu \sigma \nu \tau} x^{\sigma} x^{\tau} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ (where $R_{\mu \sigma \nu \tau}$ is evaluated at the point in question.)

Comment: @m4r35n357 You can get a unique solution with the two initial conditions $g(p)=\eta$, $g'(p)=0$. The other solutions will be related to this by merely a co-ordinate transformation, so they wouldn't be physically different solutions. The formula by Michael Seifert seems to be using this same method.